# Request to api with HTTP basic auth is status pending until I fill in the browser popup or cancel it

Tags: asp.net, angular, basic-authentication, angular-httpclient

I have a angular website that accesses a api url with HTTP basic auth configured (asp.net core with .net 6). The thing is that the browser popup shows up immediately (because i didnt send credentials) but the request to the api is in status pending. only if I fill in the browser popup with the correct credentials or cancel the popup I will get status 200/401 depending what I did. If I enter  incorrect credentials the popup will continue appearing and the request is still status pending. Why is this happening? I want the api request to immediately show status 401 in the network and also display the popup because of it. And if I enter incorrect credentials show me again status 401.

I tried many changes to client code and server code but nothing changes.

This is my client side code -

```
 ngOnInit() { 
     this.attemptLogin();
  }
  
   attemptLogin() {

     const options: any = {
      withCredentials: true
    }

   
    this.http.get('https://localhost:7273/api/auth/authenticate', options).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('Authentication succeeded');
        } else {
          console.log('Authentication failed');
        }
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.log('Error:', error);
      }
    );
```

And this my server side code (the auth handler)

```
using HTTPBasicAuthAPI.BasicAuthentication.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text;
using HTTPBasicAuthAPI.Services;

namespace HTTPBasicAuthAPI.BasicAuthentication.Handlers
{
    public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private readonly ConfigurationService _configurationService;
       
        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(ConfigurationService configurationService,IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _configurationService = configurationService;
        }

        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                SetResponseUnauthorizedDetails();
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization header"));
            }

            var authorizationHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            if (!authorizationHeader.StartsWith("Basic ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                SetResponseUnauthorizedDetails();
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Authorization header does not start with 'Basic'"));
            }

            var authBase64Decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authorizationHeader.Replace("Basic ", "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
            var authSplit = authBase64Decoded.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);

            if (authSplit.Length != 2)
            {
                SetResponseUnauthorizedDetails();
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization header format"));
            }

            var clientId = authSplit[0];
            var clientSecret = authSplit[1];

           var credentials = _configurationService.Users.Credentials;


            if (!(credentials != null && credentials.ContainsKey(clientId) && credentials[clientId].Equals(clientSecret)))
            {
                SetResponseUnauthorizedDetails();
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail(string.Format("The secret is incorrect for the client '{0}'", clientId)));
            }


            var client = new BasicAuthenticationClient
            {
                AuthenticationType = BasicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                IsAuthenticated = true,
                Name = clientId
            };

            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(client, new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, clientId)
            }));

             return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, Scheme.Name)));
            
        }

        private void SetResponseUnauthorizedDetails()
        {
            string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
            Uri? refererUri;

            if (Uri.TryCreate(referer, UriKind.Absolute, out refererUri))
            {
                string clientDomain = refererUri.Host;
                Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", $"Basic realm=\"{clientDomain}\"");
            }
            else
            {
                // Fallback if parsing the referer fails
                Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this how to network looks like when navigating to the client url -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbA9s.png)